# Oracle Apex Conditional Link

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a conditional link as follows:

```
case 
    when My_Flag = 'Y' then 
    '<a href="' || apex_util.prepare_url('f?p=&APP_ID.:65:&APP_SESSION.::&DEBUG.:65:
    :P65_MY_ID_ITEM,:P65_MY_ID_ITEM_2:' || TABLE_ID || ',' || TABLE_ID_2) || '"> 
    <p>Details</p>'
else
    '<a href="' || apex_util.prepare_url('f?p=&APP_ID.        :65:&APP_SESSION.::&DEBUG.:65::
    P65_MY_ITEM_3,:P65_MY_ITEM_4:' || TABLE_ID3 || ',' || TABLE_ID4) || '"><p>Details</p>'
end my_link
```

This link takes me to page 65 as intended but...items are not being populated.
Any idea what might be happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may consider using the apex_page.get_url procedure to ensure your parameters are in the correct location. Currently you have an extra colon after the clear cache parameter.

I would also recommend using the :APP_SESSION bind variable in SQL instead of the substitution string, otherwise you'll blow out your SQL pool.

Comment: Hi Scott, 
May I ask why &APP_SESSION. but not, &APP_ID. for instance?

Comment: Well, both as a habit, but you'll have a magnitude more distinct session values than you will have applications. If you only have one app, then there wouldn't be an impact on the shared SQL pool. But if you have 1000 concurrent users, then there will be 1000 distinct queries in the pool (instead of 1 using a bind variable) - lots of hard parsing http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2012/02/apex-variables-in-sql.html

Comment: Thank you very much, Scott. I understand now.

Comment: If you change to `apex_page.get_url` you don't even need to care about session or app id, as those parameters are optional and APEX will take care of it.